# Best practices on importing JSON files from MongoDB into Nodejs app

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb

I have a database set up in MongoDB and I'm connecting to it from a Nodejs Rest API application using `mongoose`. Right now I have a folder called `db` in which I have stored only the definitions for every collection in the database as JSONs. Such JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5c8fb15c30801ghiu865gf45"
    },
    "name": "",
    "description": ""
}
```

A have a script that creates the database and adds all the collections in MongoDB.

But later I'm going to populate the collections with data. The question is: which is a best practice? To create a separate folder with the new collections (with data) that I'm going to import from the database and use that JSONs from now on, or to just override the JSONs that I'm having right now (the ones without any relevant data in them)? Should I keep the collections JSONs that I have right now just as... schemes? Is this a good practice?

Comment: 1. It's BSON and not JSON. 2. Since this is a "database" and not JSON files, then your "folder" question basically becomes redundant. You might need to think about what you are actually asking, but I generally see the current question being closed as either "unclear" ( since you don't seem to grasp the database concept, and probably need to ) or basically you are asking *"Which brand of cola do you all recommend?"*, and that's [another reason questions get closed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Could really do with some thought and revision.